# How to take selected value from json response laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get price of btc to usd using coinmarketcap's API.

```
$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
$type = json_decode($response,true);
```

> Getting 200 Ok response

```
"data": {
"symbol": "BTC",
"id": "1",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"amount": 50,
"last_updated": "2018-06-06T08:04:36.000Z",
"quote": {
"USD": {
"price": 284656.08465608465,
"last_updated": "2018-06-06T06:00:00.000Z"
},
```

> I want to get Price value from usd  but its not working when i tried

```
$examount = $type->USD->price;
```

Comment: try this `$examount = $type['USD']->price;`

Comment: @kerbholz please sir can you explain i tried with diffrent methods alot but not worked

Comment: @Rezash already tried

Comment: i think you missed one level in your json, try to put `quote` in your code, i mean something like this `$examount = $type->quote->USD->price;`

Comment: @Rezash Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
$type = json_decode($response,true);
```

It means that your object is converted to associative array,
to access the price use:

```
$type['data']['quote']['USD']['price'];
```

You should be good to go.

**Edit**
In case `$type` contains more than one element, you will need to loop them.

```
foreach($type['data'] as $singleQuote){
    $price = $singleQuote['quote']['USD']['price'];
    echo 'Quote for: '.$singleQuote['symbol'].' in USD: '.$price.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808778/trying-to-get-property-of-no-object-after-json-response-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment105757003_59808778

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing 2nd param `true` that will convert it to associative array:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
$type = json_decode($response,true);
$examount = $type['data']['quote']['USD']['price'];
```

I hope above will solve your problem as per the documentation of coinmarketcap (https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Endpoint-Overview)

Comment: its get error for lines after response "trying to get property of non object"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808778/trying-to-get-property-of-no-object-after-json-response-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment105757003_59808778

Answer (score 0):

the problem was cuased by the $request was returning null all of above are correct also